# How send JSON data on $.post() | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I tried in 2 ways:

saving the json on a var

```
var dataLog = JSON.stringify( {
  "clientId": "1",
  "sensor": "Temp",
  "dateStart": "2016-09-03 00:00:00",
  "dateEnd": "2016-09-03 00:59:59"
} );

$.post(data , {dataLog})
  .done(function( data ) {
  console.table(data);
});
```

and adding the same json directly into the data parameter

```
$.post( url, {
  "clientId": "1",
  "sensor": "Temp",
  "dateStart": "2016-09-03 00:00:00",
  "dateEnd": "2016-09-03 00:59:59"
})
  .done(function( data ) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

but none of the 2 options works, it is possible or im doing something wrong?

Comment: 2nd method should work IMO

Comment: What error is showing up for you?

Comment: Do you want the server to receive the data *as JSON*?

Comment: Second one looks fine. How are you accessing the data in the server?

Comment: i dont know what's wrong, this is the api response `Object {descripcion: "No existen o faltan datos", respuesta: "false"}`, that response it's if i write something bad or left an empty value, but i copy paste the same data into postman and it works, idk why on jQ does't

Comment: What is your backend and how it expect the posted values?

Answer (score 1):

here one example

```
var promise = $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: dataLog
});
```